# Can't terminate BizTalk instances in isolated adapter

Tags: http, adapter, biztalk, message, biztalk2006r2

Can anyone explain how I can remove service instances ?

 - I've got a few which the BizTalk console shows as "Running"

 - they are all in the Isolated Adapter 

 - tried doing a Stop with Full Stop option ... 

 - tried the Terminate Instance option ...

 - even tried deleting the BizTalk application

But they're still there ??

---

*my bad, the application delete did remove them, must have forgot to refresh*

---

Event log has the errors ...

*A request-response for the "HTTP" adapter at receive location "/foanite/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" has timed out before a response could be delivered.*

but I still don't understand why the terminate wouldn't work

Comment: When you receve the message on the HTTP receive, how long do you take to post a response?  Are ou using a two way receive?

Comment: This is my own testing, so response should be seconds 
Yeap, using a two way receive

Comment: What version of BizTalk?  What are you seeing in the message flow?  Does it die somewhere in the orchestration?

Comment: 2006 R2. 
I've deleted the entire application, so can't see any details, but from memory, Admin console was showing them as "Running service instances" even when I'd stopped the application.
The weird thing is the HTTP receive was the beginning of the orchestration, and it had passed through those stages Ok

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem again?

Comment: Everything seems to be working Ok when I do the usual Stop with Full Stop option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running an Receive Location in an isolated host you normally need to perform a *iisreset* to be able to delete them.

Comment: Or just kill the w3wp.exe process of your isolated host.

Comment: No. Doesn't help me. Neither restart IIS nor kill w3wp.exe on both our BizTalk nodes.

Comment: @EivindGussiåsLøkseth - Are the instances "running" and in a "Isolated host"?

Comment: Yes, it's a BizTalkServerIsolated host. I'm able to remove the Active instances after doing iisreset on both nodes and delete the application. I also uninstall its msi and manually remove assemblies from Program Files (x86) and GAC to make sure I'm in a clean state before redeploying a new version. Not yet quite sure what's strictly necessary to do of all this. And it would be interesting to know the root cause, that makes these hanging Active instances.

Comment: @EivindGussiåsLøkseth There is a somewhat undocumented stored procedure in the BizTalk message-box database called dbo.int_AdminTerminateInstance_BizTalkServerApplication which should work in your scenario. You need the service instance id and service type but they are easily accessible in BizTalk Administration. If you can simulate the issue in a dev or test environment try it there first. And make a backup!

Answer (score 2):

If the IISReset does't help (it often doesn't) then use the BizTalk Health Monitor.

- Select "Maintenance" from left-and tree view
- For Task Type, select "Delete" and "Terminate Single Instance (Hard Termination)"
- Paste the instance id taken from the BizTalk admin console
- Click "Execute Task"

Comment: Invalid BizTalk version. I have BT2016 with FU3_CU7. If someone knows how to delete instances from the DB, please share the SQL script on GitHub.